# how to store an ip address in c++?

Tags: .net, c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I am creating a p2p c++ library, where I intend to maintain a linked list of members (their Ip  addresses and ports for communications), identical on every members. What C++ data type should I use to store IP addresses? string, long int? so that I can easily use them for UDP communications later on, possibly using sendto and recvfrom routines.

Comment: You should probably use whatever data type is being used by the portable socket library you plan to use for it. Also you should think about whether you want to only store IPs or also hostnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new datatype. You may be able to get some inspiration from previous attempts at this:

- Boost.Asio [ip::address](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address.html)
- Poco::Net [IPAddress](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.IPAddress.html)
- .Net [System.Net.IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- Java [java.net.InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

An IPv4 is 32 bit, so a long should be enough.

An IPv6 is 128 bit, so you need a larger type if you want to be compatible with that protocol.

Anyway, I'd go for a `std::string` object, so it will be fine whatever protocol you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IPV4, use a long which you populate with [MAKEIPADDRESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761385%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) macro

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you should use [`SOCKADDR_STORAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740504%28VS.85%29.aspx) to store addresses. Don't forget that boost and Java just additional implementation on the top of the Windows base libraries and you could use Windows API in C++, too. (I am not sure about .Net.)